# Suggest the got-my-answer fellows to answer an unanswered question

Tags: feature-request

If there is a question with say 'x' tag which remains unanswered (no accepted answer) for a 'Y' unit of time (days), how about adding a feature:

> to suggest those who have asked a
>   question  with 'x' tag previously and
>   have accepted an answer to help with
>   this question.

I can understand: if its a generic tag like, c, linux, xml, android, etc. there will be a big list of people who are eligible for such option.. however with active stackoverflowers I don't think the list can be very big.

This will be a very useful feature for those who are stuck and struggling in niche areas, especially where the call is subjective, and there is hardly any documentation available..and solution lies in the minds of only experienced ones..

May be user can be given an option to check a check-box to request for 'got-my-answer' fellows after 'y' unit of time (days) has passed after asking the question (only if there is no accepted answer till that time).

EDIT:
When the 'y' unit of time elapses, maximum top ten got-my-answer stackoverflowers with highest reputation at that moment and have 'all/most-of the tags related to that question' (criteria) can be suggested automatically by the system.

EDIT2:
Looks like there are less takers for this! Still I think, this would be an attractive feature for this already a great site for programmers!! Also there is scope for new kinds of badges..

Comment: Some people only ask. Some people only answer. Getting an answer shouldn't leave you feeling you now owe the site an answer in return. Many people ask in different tags than they could answer in.

Comment: Very true! I agree about users should not feel they owe something to site once their Qs gets answered. That is why I meant suggest to the top ten stackoverflowers with that set of tags, normally these people are known to help others which is indicated by their rep.